# MySQL grouping in a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have a table "animals"

[image: table animals]

I'm trying to figure out how many animals do I have in these two categories:
Reptile: chelonian, crocodilian, lizard, snake 
and
Rodent: hamster, porcupine, dormouse, capybara

When I write for one category:

```
SELECT Reptiles
FROM    (Select distinct COUNT(an_id) as Reptiles
         from animals
         Where an_type in ('chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard', 'snake'))rep;
```

I get the right answer:

reptiles = 9

Then I want to add the second column Rodents, so I wrote:

```
SELECT Reptiles, Rodents
FROM    (Select distinct COUNT(an_id) as Reptiles
        from animals
        Where an_type in ('chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard', 'snake'))rep
            (Select distinct count(an_id) as Rodents
            from animals
            where an_type in ('hamster', 'porcupine', 'dormouse', 'capybara'))rod
;
```

And of course I get a syntax error.

I just want to have two columns Reptiles and Rodents with the number of animals (an_id).
Can someone show me the proper way to write this query?

Thank you in advance,

Didi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed **Comma**(,) while seperating the table

> Where an_type in ('chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard', 'snake'))rep
>   **,**
>               (Select distinct count(an_id) as Rodents

Try like this

```
SELECT Reptiles, Rodents
FROM 
    (
     Select distinct COUNT(an_id) as Reptiles
     From animals
     Where an_type in ('chelonian', 'crocodilian', 'lizard', 'snake')
    ) rep,
    (
     Select distinct count(an_id) as Rodents
     from animals
     where an_type in ('hamster', 'porcupine', 'dormouse', 'capybara')
    )rod
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing comma(,) above this line ?

```
(Select distinct count(an_id) as Rodents
```